# onActivityResult not passing requestCode

Tags: java, android, flutter, android-studio, xamarin.android

in my app I made a code that when I choose an image from gallery or camera the image should be sent on chat, but when I do that the app returns on chat activity without the image sent. Bellow is the code I made:

```
sendMedia.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //check if storage permission exists
                if (!checkStoragePermission()) {
                    requestStoragePermission();
                }else {
                    pickFromGallery();
                }
            }
        });

        takePhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //check if camera permission exists
                if (!checkCameraPermission()) {
                    requestCameraPermission();
                }else {
                    pickFromCamera();
                }
            }
        });

private void pickFromGallery() {
        //pick from gallery
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_PICK_GALLERY_CODE);
    }

    private void pickFromCamera() {
        //open camera and pick image
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "Temp Pick");
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "Temp Descr");
        imageUri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_PICK_CAMERA_CODE);
    }

private void sendImageMessage(Uri imageUri) throws IOException {
        ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Sending Image.");
        progressDialog.show();

        String timeStamp = ""+System.currentTimeMillis();

        String filePath = "ChatImages/"+"post_"+timeStamp;

        Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
        byte[] data = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        StorageReference reference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child(filePath);
        reference.putBytes(data)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Task<Uri> uriTask = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
                        while (!uriTask.isSuccessful());
                        String downloadUri = uriTask.getResult().toString();

                        if (uriTask.isSuccessful()) {
                            DatabaseReference reference1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

                            HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                            hashMap.put("sender", firebaseUser.getUid());
                            hashMap.put("receiver", userId);
                            hashMap.put("message", downloadUri);
                            hashMap.put("timestamp", timeStamp);
                            hashMap.put("type", "image");
                            hashMap.put("isseen", false);

                            reference1.child("chats").push().setValue(hashMap);

                            DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users").child(firebaseUser.getUid());
                            databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                                    Users users = snapshot.getValue(Users.class);

                                    if (notify) {
                                    }
                                    notify = false;
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(MessageActivity.this, "Failed to send image.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
    }

@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE: {
                if (grantResults.length>0) {
                    boolean cameraAccepted = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    boolean storageAccepted = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    if (cameraAccepted && storageAccepted) {
                        pickFromCamera();
                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Camera and storage permissions should be accepted.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }else {
                }
            }
            break;
            case STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE: {
                if (grantResults.length>0) {
                    boolean storageAccepted = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    if (storageAccepted) {
                        pickFromGallery();
                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Storage permissions should be accepted.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (resultCode == IMAGE_PICK_GALLERY_CODE) {
                imageUri = data.getData();
                try {
                    sendImageMessage(imageUri);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }else if (requestCode == IMAGE_PICK_CAMERA_CODE) {
                try {
                    sendImageMessage(imageUri);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Well, I think there is a bug on requestCode of the onActivityResult method. Is there another way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have messed request code and result code in `onActivityResult`, in first line you are comparing request and result, these won't never be `==` (or will always be if `IMAGE_PICK_GALLERY_CODE` is set to `-1` like `RESULT_OK` [is](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#RESULT_OK))

```
    if (requestCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (resultCode == IMAGE_PICK_GALLERY_CODE) {
```

some camera/gallery apps may return wrong result code, still returning also data/images, so checking `requestCode` and proper payload in `data` `Intent` should be sufficient

```
    if (requestCode == IMAGE_PICK_GALLERY_CODE && data!= null) {
        imageUri = data.getData();
        if (imageUri != null)
            ...rest of code
    else if (requestCode == IMAGE_PICK_CAMERA_CODE) {
        ...
```

Comment: Hello, I made the changes but it still has the same issue. Is there an other way to do that?

Comment: yes, you can obtain proper permissions and make own gallery picker `Activity` + another `Activity` for handling camera instance for taking photo. A LOT work to do, current approach saves you a lot of time... and is reliable, works fine, if there are no bugs in your code ;) put some `Log.i` in methods and check at which moment `Log.i` isn't called and look in there your mistake (add codes and method names to logs)

Comment: I see. Thank you very much for your help. I appreciate it!

Comment: btw. also call `super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);` only if you won't handle payload, so if `sendImageMessage` call is reached then don't call this `super` method. calling it at first line may make some clean up in `data` and remove returned payload. I'm not sure if this may happen in this particular case, but generally may happen, so just for clean code purposes...

Comment: consider upvoting/accepting answer if helpful :) good luck!

Comment: Of course i will upvote your answer was so helpful !!

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, `onActivityResult` is always called after you get back to your activity from the activity you opened using `startActivityForResult`

I believe you mixed between `requestCode` and `resultCode`.
It’s the request code that should be either `IMAGE_PICK_GALLERY_CODE` or `IMAGE_PICK_CAMERA_CODE`.

You should first check the request code and only then the result code (maybe there are custom results for a specific request).

Also, I’d recommend adding logs right after the function starts and print all of the arguments for easy debugging.

Enjoy :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What do you mean with adding logs?

Comment: Use LogCat to print the function parameters:

private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";
Log.i(TAG, "onActivityResult resultCode ” + resultCode + “requestCode “ + requestCode);

Comment: Oh okay I see what you mean. Thank you very much!